# Nested JSON path

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, jsonpath, for-json

I have a table in the following format -

```
orderNumber  |  orderName
-------------+------------
1            |  Pizza
1            |  Pasta
```

Using SQL query, I am expecting output in the following format -

```
{
    "data": [{
        "orderNumber":1,
        "orders": [
            {"orderName": "Pizza"},
            {"orderName": "Pasta"}
        ]
    }]
}
```

But my actual output is in the following format -

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "orderNumber": 1,
            "orders" [
                {"orderName": "Pizza"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "orderNumber": 1,
            "orders": [
                {"orderName": "Pasta"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

SQL query which I am using is -

```
SELECT
    (SELECT orderNumber as orderNumber,
        (SELECT orderName
         FROM sample_table b
         WHERE a.orderNumber = b.orderNumber
         FOR JSON PATH) AS orders
     FROM sample_table a FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('data')
    ) AS orderdata
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Per the question guidelines, please avoid posting data as images and use text instead.  I've updated the question as such.

Comment: `$.data` should be a JSON array, not object (e.g `"data: [...]"`).

Answer (score 1):

You want a grouping query

```
select 
   orderNumber,
   (select orderName 
    from sample_table b 
    where a.orderNumber = b.orderNumber 
    for json path) as orders 
from sample_table a 
group by orderNumber
for json path, root ('data')
```

returns

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "orderNumber": 1,
            "orders": [
                {
                    "orderName": "Pizza"
                },
                {
                    "orderName": "Pasta"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

what if the query has non-aggreagate field like "orderName" -
 
select 
   orderNumber, orderName,
   (select orderName 
    from sample_table b 
    where a.orderNumber = b.orderNumber 
    for json path) as orders 
from sample_table a 
group by orderNumber
for json path, root ('data')

How to deal with the above query?

Comment: @SaitejaSedate, not sure I follow. OrderName either is agrregated or is not. It cann't be both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
--You Can use distinct query to do so.

create table #temp
(orderNumber varchar(20),
orderName varchar(20))

insert into #temp 
values('1','Pizza'),
('1','Pasta'),
('2','KFC'),('2','MACD')

select distinct(orderNumber),
   (select orderName 
    from #temp b 
    where a.orderNumber = b.orderNumber 
    for json path) as orders 
from #temp a 
for json path, root ('data')
```